# Debugging Java process getting killed in 1 hour

Tags: java, aws-ssm

I am working on a Java service, which needs to be invoked using a Python script, somewhat like this:

```
def start_java_service(self, set_id):
            p = subprocess.Popen(['nohup', 'java', '-jar', 'SetProcessor.jar', set_id], cwd='/path/to/jar/directory')
```

This python script will be invoked by **Amazon SSM agent**. The problem is, as soon as Java service completes 1 hour of execution, its getting killed automatically.

What are the debugging steps for this problem?

### Edit

I found out that if I am running Java service myself, it's working just fine. But, if it's being invoked by SSM, it's getting killed exactly after **1 hour**.

Answer (score 1):

There could be various reasons,

- most common one is consuming too much memory, which may trigger OS to kill the process: to troubleshoot this one just run

  dmesg | grep 'killed process'

To better understand where memory goes you can use jmap,

- another might be due to an unhadnled exception in this case make sure you are checking the logs.

Comment: I tried to slow down Java process, if there could be an exception, it wouldn't be raised after **exactly 1 hour**, every time.

Comment: Any useful info in  /var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log or /var/log/amazon/ssm/errors.log